# Bunch of queries with dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

At first im getting some `instructions` from `mysql` query

**Getting instructions**

```
function getAllInstructions(req,res){
    let mysqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM instructions where id = '` + req.params.id + "'";
    connection.query(mysqlQuery, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        var instructions = new Array(); // <-- Getting my instructions there
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length;i++) {
             var instruction = new Instruction();
             instruction.id = rows[i].id;
             instruction.title = rows[i].title;
             instructions.push(instruction);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    } 
});}
```

Every single instruction has its own `steps`.
And after i finish getting instructions i need to get an array of `steps` for each instruction i got.

**Function which is getting thoose steps**

```
function getStepsForInstruction(_instructionId){
    let mysqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM steps where steps.instruction_id =  '` + _instructionId + "'";
    var steps = [];
    connection.query(mysqlQuery, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        var steps = [];
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            var step = new Step();
            step.id = rows[i].id;
            step.title = rows[i].title;
            steps.push(step);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }
});}
```

So I want to do something like this

```
for (var i=0;i<instructions.length;i++) {
     instructions[i].steps = getStepsForInstruction(instructions[i].id);
}
```

How can i do that using `async` or common?

Comment: Your `getAllInstructions` is wide open to SQL Injection attacks. More: http://bobby-tables.com If you're using [this MySQL node lib](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values), then: `connection.query('SELECT * FROM instructions where id = ?', [req.params.id], callback);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's important to have `getAllInstructions` continue to return instructions without steps, I would change those functions so that they return promises (and use correct parameter escaping, and a couple of other minor things like `[]` instead of `new Array`, `Array#map`):

```
function getAllInstructions(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM instructions where id = ?', [req.params.id], function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var instructions = rows.map(function(row) {
                    var instruction = new Instruction();
                    instruction.id = row.id;
                    instruction.title = row.title;
                    return instruction;
                });
                resolve(instructions);
            }
        });
    });
}

function getStepsForInstruction(_instructionId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM steps where steps.instruction_id = ?', [_instructionId], function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var steps = rows.map(function(row) {
                    var step = new Step();
                    step.id = row.id;
                    step.title = row.title;
                    return step;
                });
                resolve(steps);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

...and then use `Promise.all`:

```
getAllInstructions(req, res).then(function(instructions) {
    return Promise.all(instructions.map(function(instruction) {
        return getStepsForInstruction(instruction.id).then(function(steps) {
            instruction.steps = steps;
            return instruction;
        });
    });
}).then(function(instructions) {
    // They're all done, render them here
});
```

But ideally, `getAllInstructions` would fill in the steps for us, which simplifies things:

```
function getAllInstructions(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM instructions where id = ?', [req.params.id], function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var instructionPromises = rows.map(function(row) {
                    var instruction = new Instruction();
                    instruction.id = row.id;
                    instruction.title = row.title;
                    return getStepsForInstruction(instruction.id).then(function(steps) {
                        instruction.steps = steps;
                        return instruction;
                    });
                });
                resolve(Promise.all(instructionPromises));
            }
        });
    });
}

// (getStepsForInstruction is like my earlier one)

// Usage:
getAllInstructions(req, res).then(function(instructions) {
    // They're all done, render them here
});
```

---

Note that in the above, I've manually handled creating the promises for the queries, but there are libraries that you can use to "promisify" standard Node-style callback APIs so you don't have to do it manually. (A search should turn up some options for that.)

Comment: You are my hero